# Mount a volume to share the result of a docker container in a jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

Well my problem is:

I have a shared folder `emptyDirVolume(mountPath: '/home', memory: false),`

and well I'm running in the docker file automated tests and those tests are being saved to a folder in the home directory of the docker container. Well what I want to do is share that directory with the container node to upload the results to another container with `gsutils`.

What I'm doing is `docker run -v /home:/home/tests test` but the node container home directory is empty. I tested my dockerfile locally and is working, this is doable?

I will post the code of the jenkinsfile and the dockerfile.

*JENKINSFILE:*

```
GString podName = "${name}-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
podTemplate(name: "jnlp",
  label: podName,
  namespace: "jenkins",
  containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'node', image: 'gcr.io/xyz', ttyEnabled: true),  
  ],
  volumes: [
    hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/usr/bin/docker', hostPath: '/usr/bin/docker'),
    hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
    emptyDirVolume(mountPath: '/home', memory: false),
    secretVolume(secretName: 'kube-jenkins-gcloud-secret', mountPath: '/usr/opt/gcloud/.config')
  ])
  {
    node(podName) {
      //stageWithSlackNotification() {
        stage('build docker image') {
          checkout scm
          container('node') {
            sh "docker build -t test ."
          }
        }

        stage('test') {
          checkout scm  
          container('node') {
            currentBuild.displayName = env.BUILD_NUMBER
            currentBuild.description = env.BUILD_NUMBER

            sh "docker run -v /home:/home/tests test"
          }
        }

         stage('testv2') {
          checkout scm  
          container('node') {

            sh "ls /home"
          }
        }

      //}
    }
  }
```

*DOCKERFILE*

```
FROM gcr.io/xyz

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/opt/hold-ats
WORKDIR /usr/opt/hold-ats

COPY package* ./

RUN npm install

COPY src src

RUN mkdir -p /home/tests

CMD ["./node_modules/.bin/newman", "run", "src/collections/smoke_tests.json", "-e",  "src/environments/dev.json", "--reporter-htmlextra-export", "/home/tests" ,"--reporter-htmlextra-darkTheme", "--reporter-htmlextra-testPaging", "-r", "htmlextra"]
```

Anyone knows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related with the usage of the docker deamon while executing jenkins pipeline stages inside a container managed by Kubernetes.

When you use `docker run`, the docker deamon that you have is the one on the host machine, as declared here:

```
hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/usr/bin/docker', hostPath: '/usr/bin/docker'),
hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
```

So, when you use the volume mapping `-v /home:/home/tests`, the directory `/home` of the host is used and NOT the `/home` directory of the container created by the kubernetes plugin.

To solve this problem you can do one of two things:

1. Configure a different docker deamon inside of the kubernetes managed container that is executing the pipeline stage.
2. Map the same directory to be accessible both on the `docker run` and kubernetes container.

The second option seems simpler IMHO and can be achieved with:

- Add a new volume mapping to the kubernetes podTemplate: `hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/home/tests', hostPath: '/tmp/tests'),`
- Use the same directory when running your container: `docker run -v /tmp/tests:/home/tests test`

Have fun!!